# Using Facebook data to populate Wordpress user profile fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, facebook

I've scoped the necessary extended permissions for my Facebook login button, but now I assume that I need to alter the user-functions.php in order to populate my user metadata with the extended permissions.  The extended permissions are: user_likes, user_education_history, and user_work_history.  I have created corresponding user meta fields that are: Interests, Education, and Employment.  This is the current user-functions.php:

```
/* Update user profile from facebook */

function userpro_update_profile_via_facebook($user_id, $array) {

    global $userpro;

    extract($array);



    if ( userpro_is_logged_in() && ( $user_id != get_current_user_id() ) && !current_user_can('manage_options') )

        die();



    if ($id && $id != 'undefined') { update_user_meta($user_id, 'userpro_facebook_id', $id); }



    if ($first_name && $first_name != 'undefined'){ update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $first_name); }

    if ($last_name && $last_name != 'undefined') { update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', $last_name); }



    if ($gender && $gender != 'undefined') { update_user_meta($user_id, 'gender', $gender); }



    if ($link && $link != 'undefined') { update_user_meta($user_id, 'facebook', $link); }
```

I was wondering if anyone had any tips for connecting these three extended permissions with my user data.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a facebook API to do that, check this out, [Retrieve User's Profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/4.0.0)

Take a look aswell at [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/) this will give an hint about what information you can retrieve.